# Will a SAPUI5 app deployed in HCP sync oData?

Tags: sapui5, sap-cloud-platform

I have an existing app which I wish to deploy on HANA Cloud Platform as a Mobile app.

Will the oData by available when offline and will it sync when online again?

Answer (score 0):

SAPUI5 does not have built-in offline capabilities. You will have to implement your own offline storage mechanism. You can use HTML5 localStorage or IndexedDB to implement this. Something like [PouchDB](https://pouchdb.com/) can be useful to store data locally as it is cross browser compliant. To sync again when you are online you will have to trigger this with some additional code as oData requests are sent as & when required by a particular UI5 control. oData request sent will  not depend on application being online or offline.

Comment: That's not true, I've since figured out that SAP WEB IDE has a Kapsel Offline Template.  Now I'm trying to figure out if I can deploy this on Mobile Secure?

Comment: I think you may be right. This seems possible with the Hybrid Application Tookit for Kapsel Apps

Comment: Can you then deploy this using mobile secure?

Comment: I am sorry, but I am not much aware of mobile secure